# How does interrupt controller deals with PCI, QPI and other buses?

Tags: networking, memory, keyboard, cpu, pci-express

[We know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motherboard#Integrated_peripherals) that communication between CPU and Notrh Bridge things happens through the PCIe or memory bus. Communication between CPU and South Bridge devices is made through the interconnect interface (seems QPI in Intel's case). E.g. communication with keyboard will not involve PCI/PCIe buses at all. But what exacly means "communication"? How interrupt handling lays on this concept? Where APIC (or something else) is located, an how this is deals with QPI, Front-side bus, LPC bus, etc.

I'm very sorry if this is obvious but still can't figure out.